# Array of Singleton class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, singleton, shared

As the titles says, I need to implement an array of singleton class.
My project idea is building a simple PLC-Ladder IDE written in Microsoft Visual C#.
Because I'm not an expert code writer, I wrote a large proportion of my code in a single file. It worked properly, but it was not easy to read and update. So I split it in five different classes.

```
MainClass.cs - Main program  
CustomMethods.cs - All my methods  
CustomEventHandlers.cs - All my event handlers  
Components.cs - This class holds information (name, type, input, output, etc) and I need a 2-D array of this, because I'm using it as a "screen buffer" for the project.  
SharedVariables.cs - All my variables are declared here. My components class is initialized as a 2-D array in here too.
```

The problem is that I cannot create and share an instance of "Components" array between my classes. I found the "Singleton pattern", but still I cannot implement it properly. I can't initialize my array of "singleton" class. Here is the code (irrelevant parts are cut out).

```
//Custom method.cs
namespace AVR_PLC
{
    class CustomMethods
    {
        CustomEventHandlers extHandlers;
        SharedVariables Variables;

        public void setup()
        {
            extHandlers = new CustomEventHandlers();
            Variables = new SharedVariables();

                for (int i = 0; i < Variables.maxX; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < Variables.maxY; j++)
                        Variables.pBuffer[i, j] = new Components;
        }  
---------------------------------------------  
//SharedVariables.cs
namespace AVR_PLC
{
    class SharedVariables
    {
        public int maxX = 10;
        public int maxY = 100;
        public Components[,] pBuffer = Components[10, 100];    //Panel buffer

    }
}  
---------------------------------------------  
//Components.cs
namespace AVR_PLC
{
    public class Components
    {
        //***** Singleton pattern implementation ***********
        //Private static object.
        private static volatile Components instance;
        private static readonly object mutex = new Object();

        //Private constructor to prevent object creation.
        private Components() 
        {

        }

        //Public property to access outside of the class to create an object.
        public static Components Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    lock (mutex)
                        if (instance == null)
                            instance = new Components();
                return instance;
            }
        }
        //************************************************
        private string _name = "Default name";

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this._name; }
            set { this._name = value; }
        }
        public void reset()
        {
            _name = "Default name";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Array of Singleton sounds like a contradiction. The purpose of singleton is that you have only one instance of a class. Making a array of that seems strange.

Comment: How can I have a single instance of array of class shared between multiple classes? That's my problem. 
The class in my code above is shortened. It contains more variables (type, input, ouput, comment etc.)

Comment: You really need to learn object oriented programming. What you've written is God-Object Anti-Pattern

Comment: I am not familiar with object oriented programming. I' m learning through trying and testing (I should study it first, hah? :P). My original problem is sharing an instance of array of class between classes. The "singleton pattern" is something new to me. I've known it for no more than a couple of hours. I now understand that what I've written above is a paradox. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A singleton is a class which there is only one instance of (Personally, when using C# I prefer static classes instead of singletons).

To access the singleton class you use the `Components.Instance` property. BUT, in your case, you dont actually want a singleton.
If you want an array of Component objects, you would rather want to create a new one for each new object in the array, else the array is kinda useless (if its exactly the same object in it...).

To share a variable between multiple instances of the same class you use the `static` keyword, which basically makes it the same object over all classes (if you change it in one, it changes in all).
So you could just make your shared variables class a static class:

```
public static class SharedVariables
{
    public static int maxX = 10;
    public static int maxY = 100;
    public static Components[,] pBuffer = Components[10, 100];
}
```

And they will be reachable wherever you access the SharedVariables class.

The big questions is though: Do you really need a static `SharedVariables` class? I kinda suspect you got a design issue here to think about.

Comment: The thing is I have a great deal of variables in my SharedVariable class. Should I use the static keyword everywhere? I think I saw something like a static constructor for classes. I'm not sure. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: There is a static constructor yes. You could make your SharedVariables class into a singleton if you dont want to use all static properties, but personally I would think about if the class even is supposed to exist and the variables shouldnt be placed in other classes and be kept private there. I cant say anything for sure about that though, as i havent seen the whole code :P

Comment: So basically all you "need" to do to make your current code to work is to implement the `singleton pattern` on the `SharedVariables` class instead of the `Components` class, then access it via `SharedVariables.Instance.Property;` instead of `SharedVariables.Property`;

Comment: I am used in C coding. In C, I could make a header file for my project and place all my constants and global variables there. In C#, I can't create a .h file. The only way I can get close to headers, is by creating another class. That's the purpose of "SharedVariable" existence.

Comment: So I turn my     Components class to static and implement the singleton pattern on     SharedVariables. Let me try this. Thanks for helping.

Comment: No, keep the Components class none-static, you wish to instanciate new objects for each Component in the array (I guess at least, hehe). Only change the `SharedVariables` class.

Comment: All the errors and warnings relating to `SharedVariables` are now gone. The program does not work as planned, but that is another story for me. I solved my original problem (for which I opened this topic). I really appreciate your help. Thank you. @Jite